# set terminal width in a debian shell?

Tags: shell, debian

How do I set the terminal width in a shell session on a debian machine? I'm talking about the Alt+Fn terminals, not a GUI terminal program. Right now it's at 80x25 (I guess), and I'd like it bigger.

Comment: actually, you might look into changing the size of the framebuffer in use on the console.  80x25 sounds like your FB (assuming you're even using one) is in a basic 640x480 resolution.  hopefully someone else will step up and explain better how to do that (it could be as simple as a boot-time option, and could be much more complicated; i get rather lost with that stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [`resizecons`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resizecons) a try.

Comment: also related commands setterm and stty, depending on whether he's trying to affect one virtual terminal or many.